# Creating virtual directory under a specific website with NANT

Tags: xml, nant

I am able to create a virtual directory with 'mkiisdir', but it creates under default website only.

With using IISServer attribute it works fine in my test environment but not in Production env.

Scenario 1 (Test env)

1. IIS with 2 websites, 1 hosted on 80
   & other on 88.
2. Use attribute IIServer='localhost' &
   port ='88', it creates the virtual
   directory under the right website

Scenario 2 (Production env)

1. IIS with 2 websites, 1 hosted on 80
   & other as well on 80 but with a different hostheader.

What value should i use for IISServer & port so that virtual directory gets created under the website with the host header.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is very old but we recently encountered the same problem. If you are using **IIS 7 (or above)** then there is a work-around. You can use [`AppCmd.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that comes with IIS 7 to perform lots of different actions, in your case create Applications under different web sites.

You could create a sample Nant task (macro):

```
  <macrodef name="Install.App">
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="websiteName" default="Default Web Site" />
      <attribute name="vdir" />
      <attribute name="physicalPath" />
      <attribute name="appPool" default="DefaultAppPool" />
    </attributes>

    <sequential>
      <exec program="c:\windows\System32\InetSrv\appcmd.exe" workingdir="${project::get-base-directory()}" verbose="true" failonerror="false" >
        <arg value="ADD"/>
        <arg value="APP" />
        <arg value="&quot;/site.name:${websiteName}&quot;"/>
        <arg value="/path:${vdir}" />
        <arg value="/physicalPath:${physicalPath}" />
        <arg value="/apppool.name:${appPool}" />
      </exec>

    </sequential>
  </macrodef>
```

Then you can simply call it with something like this:

```
<Install.App websiteName="SomeOtherWebsite" vdir="/MyApp" physicalPath="C:\apps\myapp" appPool="MyAppPool" />
```

This would create an application named "**MyApp**" inside the "**SomeOtherWebsite**" web site on that server.

This creates an application but you could also create a plain virtual directory by simply changing `<arg value="APP" />` to `<arg value="VDIR" />`. For more information and options you can [read more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

I hope that helps some other people who are also stuck in the same position!

Answer (score 0):

Specify iisserver parameter and identify your site be hostname:port combination

```
<mkiisdir iisserver="host:port" dirpath="c:\siteroot\test" vdirname="Test" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify website as a parameter to mkiisdir

```
<mkiisdir iisserver="host" website="${project.service.iiswebsite}" " dirpath="c:\siteroot\test" vdirname="Test"/>
```

Should work fine